# Importer module for uploading CSV in channel entries is not working for grid

Tags: channel-entries, channel, grid, solspace-importer

I am using grid in channel fields and using importer module for uploading CSV file to add/update channel data.

But importer module dose not support for grid, then is there a way how can i use importer with grid ?
Also i am having 5 grid in the channel so i can not use matrix instead of grid now.

Comment: Sounds like you might have to switch to Matrix as that may be your only option :(

Answer (score 1):

Importer module doesn't support GRID fields.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll either have to switch to Matrix or purchase Datagrab:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab

I personally prefer DG or Import. Solspace does offer a 30 Day Money Back Guarantee so I'd return it and purchase DG instead.